# Calling Google Service from Apps Script with oAuth

Tags: google-apps-script

I was trying to run the sample script of Google Apps Script here: 
https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs

I believe I set PRIVATE_KEY, CLIENT_EMAIL and USER_EMAIL correctly from JSON file downloaded from Google Developer Console. Also I enabled Google Drive API on the project. But still I get an error in the dialog "Error: invalid_client\n no application name".

Is there any code I should add / change to run this sample script correctly?

Comment: The PRIVATE_KEY, did you get it from the json obtained service account credentials? Are you using a Google for Work account?

Comment: Yes, I am using Google for Work account. I believe our domain admin give the permission though. I got private key from the JSON file.

Comment: Those are the project credentials,  the domain admin has to grant access to  that application so it can access the domain information. In this case the users impersonation. check if what i mention in my answer has been done by the admin.

Comment: Thanks so much, Gerardo. Since it is not easy for me to contact the domain admin, I have moved the script to gmail account. (And I got new credential for the script on my Gmail account). But still I get the same error. Seems like I made an elementary mistake. The USER_EMAIL is just gmail address like honey@gmail.com ?

Comment: Yes, it won't work with a gmail account. Impersonation of users only work for accounts under a domain. eg. user@mydomain.com. And this will work only after the domain administrator grants these permissions to the domain. This can be done installing the app from Marketplace or following the steps I provided in the answer. You'll have to contact your admin and ask to install the application otherwise you won't be able to test the app.

Comment: Thanks so much, Gerardo. That makes sense. I am getting my own domain  for Google for Work and will test it soon.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the correct settings (PRIVATE_KEY,CLIENT_EMAIL and a valid USER_EMAIL), the error could also be related to the permission granted to the application from the domain admin.

Since this example uses domain wide delegation of authority to impersonate the account from the USER_EMAIL, first the domain admin has to grant permissions to the application to perform this kind of operations.

To grant this permissions to the app you can do it by going to: your Admin Console -> Security -> Advanced Settings -> Manage API client access

There you will add the service account CLIENT_ID in the field "Client Name"  and in the second field you will add your project scopes separated by commas. These scope should match the scopes that the application uses. In this case id Drive scope and any other you may be using.

Click the button "Authorize" and if everything goes well, then you will be able to impersonate users in your domain with that project.

Here is the related [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation). I hope this helps.